# How to setup a mixed C / Z80-assembler toolchain in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, toolchain, z80

I want to use Visual Studio Code for writing code for [my homebrew Z80 Computer](https://github.com/obiwanjacobi/Zalt).
I use [z88dk](http://www.z88dk.org/forum/forums.php) and its tools to compile C, assemble the Z80 asm files etc. I will write parts in assembler and other parts in C. I also need to edit .m4 files. Would be nice if these file types would have syntax coloring.

I am totally new to vscode and I have seen some languages for the z80 but I have no idea how to continue from there - or if these will even work at all.

I don't want to have to write a language extension because that looks like just too much work - from what I understand. I am also not a typescript/javascript developer.

Is there a tutorial out there on how to set this up, or any other helpful resources?

Comment: A fun aside - check out Color Gameboy development when you get a chance.  It was done on a Z80 (esque) platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm looking this up as I type so it may not be sufficiently complete to warrant a tick but I hope it'll be useful.

Per [Adding Language Colorization](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/colorizer) you can use TextMate-format colourisation rules so jumping through those rules with something like [this 'Z80 Asm' rule set](https://github.com/psbhlw/sublime-text-z80asm/blob/master/z80asm/z80asm.tmLanguage) should get you syntax highlighting. It doesn't look like it's a lot of work given that somebody else has already written the highlighting rules.

[Microsoft's documentation on Tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) also guides you through using `tasks.json` to incorporate into your workspace "a task runner like gulp or grunt or any command line tool like a compiler or linter". So you should be able to create a z88dk running task fairly easily.

Comment: Thanks. I finaly found the tasks.json and pretty much got that working the way I wanted. I found the terms tasks and commands used very confusing. Also how they (sort of) supported multipl tasks. The syntax coloring is harder. It seems you do have to write a language extension for that. I've installed the Z80-asm extension and that seems to work ok, although the colors are not my choice - but its better than nothing.